# Good semantics, Subclass or emulate?

Tags: coding-style, python

I have been using python for a while now and Im happy using it in most forms but I am wondering which form is more pythonic. Is it right to emulate objects and types or is it better to subclass or inherit from these types. I can see advantages for both and also the disadvantages. Whats the correct method to be doing this?

Subclassing method

```
class UniqueDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        dict.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key not in self:
            dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
        else:
            raise KeyError("Key already exists")
```

Emulating method

```
class UniqueDict(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.di = dict(*args, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key not in self.di:
            self.di[key] = value
        else:
            raise KeyError("Key already exists")
```

Comment: Your methods are not equivalent. The second implementation lacks several methods to make it a valid mapping object.

Comment: Its a stripped down example imagine I have emulated the other methods

Comment: @Jakob Bowyer: Why write every single dictionary method out to "emulate" a dictionary?  What's the point in writing all that error-prone code?

Comment: Hmmm But what if you 'are' changing most of the methods a dict has.

Comment: @Jakob Bowyer: "what if you 'are' changing most of the methods a dict has?"  What?  So neither class is `dict`-like?  Please **update** the question to explain how it's sensible to extend a `dict` to make it not `dict`-like?  What -- exactly -- are you doing?

Comment: Im not doing anything at the moment, I just answered another question where I used inheritance from a dict I was wondering if there is advantage to emulating it.

Comment: @Jakob Bowyer: "if there is advantage to emulating it"?  What possible advantage can there be from rewriting the entire thing yourself?  Why write every single dictionary method out to "emulate" a dictionary? What's the point in writing all that error-prone code?  Please explain -- exactly -- what you're trying to do.

Comment: Im honestly not doing anything just thinking about it. Seems like inherit is the better way of doing this. I was just trying to get both sides of the argument.

Comment: @Jakob Bowyer:  I don't think there is a "both sides".  I can't understand how there can be confusion.  Either it's dict-like or it's not dict-like.  If it's like a dict that's one thing.  If it's not like a dict that's an entirely separate thing.  The very idea of "emulating" a type but not actually being that type is very, very confusing.  Can you explain what this "emulation" thing might mean.  I can't understand how there can even be a doubt or a question about how to proceed.  Maybe a more complete example would show where the "both sides" thing arises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Key question you have to ask yourself here is:

> "How should my class change if the 'parent' class changes?"

Imagine new methods are added to `dict` which you don't override in your `UniqueDict`. If you want to express that **`UniqueDict` is simply a small derivation** in behaviour from `dict`'s behaviour, then you'd **go with inheritance** since you will get changes to the base class automatically. If you want to express that **`UniqueDict` kinda looks like a `dict` but actually isn't**, you should go with the **'emulation' mode**.

Comment: Thats a nice way of thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Subclassing is better as you won't have to implement a proxy for every single dict method.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for subclass, and for the reason I would refer to the motivation of [PEP 3119](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/#rationale):

> For example, if asking 'is this object
>   a mutable sequence container?', one
>   can look for a base class of 'list',
>   or one can look for a method named
>   '**getitem**'. But note that although
>   these tests may seem obvious, neither
>   of them are correct, as one generates
>   false negatives, and the other false
>   positives.
>
> The generally agreed-upon remedy is to
>   standardize the tests, and group them
>   into a formal arrangement. This is
>   most easily done by associating with
>   each class a set of standard testable
>   properties, either via the inheritance
>   mechanism or some other means. Each
>   test carries with it a set of
>   promises: it contains a promise about
>   the general behavior of the class, and
>   a promise as to what other class
>   methods will be available.

In short, it is sometimes desirable to be able to check for mapping properties using `isinstance`.